# how to disable justify in table cell using css

Tags: css

I've tried using `text-align: left` and `align: left` but it doesn't work. Note: this is for the creation of PDF using freemarker

[image]

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using :

```
p{

  text-align: left;
}


 <td align="left" class="desc"><p>Test</p></td>
```